# SpringBoot 3.x upgrade: AQjmsFactory version compatibility issue with Jakarta namespace

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, java-17, oracle-aq, jakarta-migration

While upgrading to the latest SpringBoot versions from 2.x to 3.x, I have encountered that there is version compatibility issue for Oracle Advance queue "AQjmsFactory" with Jakarta.jms package.

AQjmsFactory is providing connectionfactory of javax.jms.ConnectionFactory but SrpingBoot 3.x has upgraded with jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory package. Hence we are unable to upgrade to SpringBoot 3.x with Oracle Advance queue.

From Oracle AQ Documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJMS/oracle/jms/AQjmsFactory.html

Please let me know if there is any possible solution.

I have tried this below suggested answer, but it did not work
[Oracle Advanced Queuing and Jakarta namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72730238/oracle-advanced-queuing-and-jakarta-namespace/75421855#75421855)

Comment: If you're using Oracle AQ, then I assume you have an Oracle support contract. Contact Oracle and ask them if they have a Jakarta EE 9 or higher compatible version. Otherwise, the answer you link should do what you need, or you need to use some bytecode rewriter to change the namespaces in the library so they use the jakarta.* namespace.

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/oracle-advanced-queuing-and-jakarta-namespace-1296 (there seems to be some movement). The solution in the answer should work, what didn't work (or maybe that is better asked in a new question).